# javascript geocode latlng variable

Tags: javascript, maps, geocode

JAVASCRIPT

Im sure this a very simple problem.

I am modifying the line below and want to replace (53, 0) with a variable.  However, the variable that is created called 'result', is equal to '(34, 2)', ie it already has the brackets around it.

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng.(53, 0)
```

i have tried

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng.(result)
center: new google.maps.LatLng.result
center: new google.maps.LatLng.({result})
```

and it no working!

FULL CODE

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

```
  if (geocoder) {
     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

          window.result = results[0].geometry.location;

          alert(result);



        } 
        else {
          alert('nothing');
        }
     });
  }

  function load() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng.(53, 0),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
```

}

For reference, alert(result) returns

(53.8622017, -2.405405999999971)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try new google.maps.LatLng(result[0], result[1])? Please post where the 'result' variable is created.

Answer (score 2):

you putting . after the LatLng
the correct way to create the latlng object was 
try this way

```
center:new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
```

here . define the package level and the last latLng was class

like google is top level in that maps and in that LatLng was defined.

So the LatLng has 2 parameter (latitude and longitude)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set your map center in the response

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

  }
```